# MapReduce programmatically get current job ID

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

After I give
`JobClient.runJob(jobConf)`

How do I get the JobID of this MapReduce task?

I've seen codes like this below but it returns all the current running jobs IDs

```
System.out.println("Printing job IDs...");
JobClient client = new JobClient(jobConf);
JobStatus[] status = client.getAllJobs();
for(int i = 0; i < status.length; i++){
    if(!status[i].isJobComplete()){
        JobID jobid = status[i].getJobID();
        System.out.println(jobid.toString());
    }
}
```

Update:

Ok I've overlooked something. The `runJob` method returns a `RunningJob` object, which has the `getID` method. But the `RunningJob` object is only returned after the job has completed its run. Is there anyway to get the ID while the job is still running?

```
RunningJob currentJob = JobClient.runJob(jobConf);  
System.out.println("JobID: " + currentJob.getID().toString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SubmitJob seems to do the trick.

```
JobClient client = new JobClient(jobConf);
RunningJob currentJob = client.submitJob(jobConf);
System.out.println("JobID: " + currentJob.getID().toString());
```

Comment: If it works, accept your answer, so that others will see how it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of the job id, while the job is running, you can use the following code in the new API,

int value = job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;

JobID jobId=job.getJobID();

//your logic using jobId

return value;